# openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "key" producing an extraneous “(stdin)= ” prefix and trailing newline

Tags: openssl, stdin

if you run:

```
while read CTFid; do echo -n "$CTFid" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "key"; done < CTFid.csv > OPKlist.csv
```

i am getting (stdin) in the prefix like so

```
(stdin)=2d442d454a00c469baa7ec5deba94f172263c247
```

I am trying to use

```
"| sed 's"
```

but confused as to where the placement goes

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me on OpenSSL for IBM AIX, which also outputs this same leading `(stdin)=`. Seeing as you're using a shell one-liner, you can isolate the resulting hash by simply deleting the prefix with sed:

```
echo -n "$CTFid" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "key" | sed "s/(stdin)=//";
```

Comment: Awesome ill give it a try, thank you for your response

Comment: Just edited my comment to show you where to put the `sed`.